# Chart.js : Multiple colors for tooltipFontColor

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I know that the font color for the tooltip labels can be changed with the toolTipFontColor option, but that forces me to give one colour for all labels. Is there a way to set the colour for a label to, say, white, but then change it to red if a condition holds. I was thinking of something using the customTooltips option but any solution is welcome.

Example of what I'd like to do:

```
if (difference[i] >= 0) { 
    tooltipFontColor: "#FFF" 
} else {
    tooltipFontColor: "#F00" 
}
```

The trick is that the `difference` array can have some values above zero and some below. I want Chart.js to somehow understand that and follow through with the colours.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Different Colors for Toooltip Based on Value

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Script**

```
new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    // take over the tooltip binding
    tooltipEvents: [],
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
        // copy of chart.js binding except that ...
        Chart.helpers.bindEvents(this, ["mousemove", "touchstart", "touchmove"], function (evt) {
            var activePoints = (evt.type !== 'mouseout') ? this.getPointsAtEvent(evt) : [];
            this.eachPoints(function (point) {
                point.restore(['fillColor', 'strokeColor']);
            });
            Chart.helpers.each(activePoints, function (activePoint) {
                activePoint.fillColor = activePoint.highlightFill;
                activePoint.strokeColor = activePoint.highlightStroke;
            });
            // ... we set the font color before the tooltip is shown
            if (activePoints.length !== 0) {
                if (activePoints[0].value >= 0)
                    this.options.tooltipFontColor = "#FFF";
                else
                    this.options.tooltipFontColor = "#F00";
            }
            this.showTooltip(activePoints);
        });
    }
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uajz17yp/

Comment: Thanks for this! I am trying to have only the value displayed in red, as opposed to the value and the month. Will figure out how to do it from your code.

Comment: It might be easier to do it with a custom tooltip if that's the case - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33997843/360067. Because of where we plug in the color change, both the value and the label change color.